# iOS - Apple System Log Facility - Persistance

Tags: iphone, ios, nslog, asl

I have a question regarding Apple System Log Facility (asl) on iOS. What is the persistence of messages in asl on device? It seems to me that messages are somehow kept in the buffer on device (which gives approximately 10 minutes to the past) and accessible only thru socket and are wiped when device restarts. Is this true? Can be older logs accessed somehow after device gets jailbroken. I'm interested mainly in messages from applications (NSLog...).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the logs get wiped out if the device is rebooted. I think that the logs are kept in memory with the newer log messages replacing the older messages. I'm not sure how much of a buffer there is by default.

If you jailbreak your phone, you can set a variable (I forgot which one, but you can check the web), and then the log will be written out to a file.